# Quick x86 asm question

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I have this code in C:

```
int main(){ char a[10]; _asm{ mov DWORD PTR[a],eax;}
```

This works well, but why do I actually need the

```
DWORD PTR
```

When the DWORD size is already stated by using eax? IAnd for destination, I dont need any size whe I have pointer, right? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your code is wrong.  The *a* variable is an array, not a pointer.  Declare it char* and you don't need the override.  The code is nonsense of course.

Comment: Well, I believed that a is a pointer to the first array element. At least you can pass it to funtions that takes char* as argument....

Comment: It can be converted to a pointer.  It is automatic in the C language.  Assembly is, think about it, more strict.  Does it *really* make sense to convert a char[10] to an int32_t?  It takes a cast.  Yes, dword ptr is that cast.

Comment: It is an array.  Check your favorite C language programming book about the distinction between arrays and pointers.